# How to receive data, sent from header(location: .....) on next php page in POST method?

Tags: php, html

In `file1.php` I am sending data through this code:

```
header("Location: file2.php? age=20");
```

In `file2.php` I am hoping to get this data through POST…

```
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

…But I not getting it. I would like to get data via POST at `page2.php`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you call an URL with get-parameters you need to access this parameters also with the $_GET-method.

You access the "age"-parameter in file2.php?age=20 by

```
$_GET['age']
```

Here are two links about post and get

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Can I not get the 'age' through post method in file2.php?

Comment: if you want to work with the post-variables you need to send the data in the post-method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send POST data through a redirect. It is, however, possible to send POST data using `cURL`. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code) for an example, and the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for more info